# PHP ,MySql database

Tags: php

I am trying to test if my PHP script works by entering the values in `add.php` directly via URL but the table displays only zeroes.

The `Connect.php`is used when accessing the database. The `Connect.php` code is the one used mainly for connection here it is, the `add.php` process the POST from `arduino.indexx.php` displays the values in a table:

Below is **add.php**

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");

    $link=Connection();

    $temp1=$_POST["temp1"];
    $hum1=$_POST["hum1"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `tempLog` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
        VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$hum1."')"; 

    mysqli_query($link,$query);
    mysqli_close($link);

    header("Location: indexx.php");
?>
```

Below is **connect.php**:

```
<?php

    function Connection(){
        $server="localhost";
        $user="root";
        $pass="";
        $db="database";

        $connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
        //$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

        if (!$connection) {
            die('MySQL ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysqli_select_db($connection,$db) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

        return $connection;
    }
?>
```

**indexx.php**

```
<?php

    include("connect.php");     

    $link=Connection();

    $result=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `tempLog` ORDER BY `timeStamp` DESC");
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sensor Data</title>
   </head>
<body>
   <h1>Temperature / moisture sensor readings</h1>

   <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Hall Sensor&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Thermistor&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

      <?php 
          if($result!==FALSE){
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%s </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
                   $row["timeStamp"], $row["temperature"], $row["humidity"]);
             }
             mysqli_free_result($result);
             mysqli_close($link);
          }
      ?>

   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The url is 192.168.1.5/project/add.php?temp1=89&hum1=78

Comment: The codes have no errors

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you explain your question?

Comment: BTW your code has a lot of "errors" when it comes to sql injection. It is ready to inject.

Comment: see add.php you do not validate nor escape input from user

Comment: @ bub,at which statements wxactly

Comment: $temp1=$_POST["temp1"];
    $hum1=$_POST["hum1"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `tempLog` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
        VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$hum1."')";

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 Look here for SQL injection prevention

Comment: and how exactly do you validate input from user?

Comment: Should I google it for you? Look what @NathanvanderWerf posted

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you 'enter the values via the url', they'll end up in `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. Try changing those lines in add.php.